# Adding to Table Android TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

I want to create a very simple scheduler by inserting data into a table. I have no problem getting this information, however, I cannot seem to insert into a meaningful table. By meaningful table, I mean a table that starts out as such, with subsequent additions inserted below their respected title:

DAY 1:

DAY 2:

DAY 3:

DAY 4:

I get the course information from the user and want to categorize the courses based on when they occur in their timetable. I am having a rather difficult time organizing this into a table.

Any suggestions on how I might efficiently sort this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TableLayout` and create a template of your layout in XML. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="DAY 1:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="DAY 2:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="DAY 3:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="DAY 4:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Then inspect a list of courses information and for every course add programatically info about it as a `TableRow` to your previously created layout . Use `TableLayout#addView(View child, int index)` for that. For example to add `TableRow` containing `TextView` as the last row to `TableLayout`:

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_table_layout);
TableRow tr = new TableRow(context);
tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setText("Some text");
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tr.addView(tv);
tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: okay, that makes sense. Thank you. How would I update the table?

Comment: Create `TableRow`s and add them to `TableLayout` using `TableLayout#addView` methods. See updated answer.